# how to count multiple value in count function

Tags: sql, asp.net, count

table

```
id q1     q2     q3     q4      q5
-----------------------------------
 1 v.good good   fair good    fair
-----------------------------------
 2 good   v.good fair good    fair
```

i want answer like this

```
----------------------
status q1 q2 q3 q4 q5
----------------------
v.good  4  3  2  4  3
----------------------
good    4  5  6  7  8
----------------------
fair    5  7  6  3  9
----------------------
```

can any one help me in this problem i feel stuck 
thank in advance

Comment: Where are the numbers coming from?  You question is very unclear.

Comment: it will be count numbers from table

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your sample data is just incomplete as your expected output doesn't seem to have much of anything to do with it in terms of the counts you provided.

If that is the case my guess at interpreting what you want is:

```
select 'v.good' as status,
       sum(case when q1 = 'v.good' then 1 end) as q1,
       sum(case when q2 = 'v.good' then 1 end) as q2,
       sum(case when q3 = 'v.good' then 1 end) as q3,
       sum(case when q4 = 'v.good' then 1 end) as q4,
       sum(case when q5 = 'v.good' then 1 end) as q5
from tbl
union all
select 'good',
       sum(case when q1 = 'good' then 1 end) as q1,
       sum(case when q2 = 'good' then 1 end) as q2,
       sum(case when q3 = 'good' then 1 end) as q3,
       sum(case when q4 = 'good' then 1 end) as q4,
       sum(case when q5 = 'good' then 1 end) as q5
from tbl
union all
select 'fair',
       sum(case when q1 = 'fair' then 1 end) as q1,
       sum(case when q2 = 'fair' then 1 end) as q2,
       sum(case when q3 = 'fair' then 1 end) as q3,
       sum(case when q4 = 'fair' then 1 end) as q4,
       sum(case when q5 = 'fair' then 1 end) as q5
from tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to count the rows, this is probably more easily done in the application layer, but you can do:

```
select status, sum(q1), sum(q2), sum(q3), sum(q4), sum(q5)
from (select q1 as status, 1 as q1, 0 as q2, 0 as q3, 0 as q4, 0 as q5 from table union all
      select q2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 from table union all
      select q3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 from table union all
      select q4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 from table union all
      select q5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 from table 
     ) q
group by status;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use [PIVOT and UPIVOT operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) as follow:

To unpivot data:

```
  SELECT id, Question, Answer
  FROM (
    SELECT id, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5
    FROM Answers
    ) AS pvteddata
  UNPIVOT(Answer FOR Question IN(q1, q2, q3, q4, q5)) AS unpvted
```

Above query returns:

```
id  Question    Answer
1   q1  v.good
1   q2  good
1   q3  fair
1   q4  good
1   q5  fair
2   q1  good
2   q2  v.good
2   q3  fair
2   q4  good
2   q5  fair
3   q1  v.good
3   q2  good
3   q3  fair
3   q4  good
3   q5  good
4   q1  good
4   q2  v.good
4   q3  good
4   q4  good
4   q5  v.good
5   q1  v.good
5   q2  good
5   q3  good
5   q4  good
5   q5  fair
6   q1  good
6   q2  v.good
6   q3  v.good
6   q4  good
6   q5  fair
```

Now, you should pivot it again:

```
SELECT Answer, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5
FROM (
    -- above query
 ) AS DT
PIVOT(COUNT(Question) FOR Answer IN(q1, q2, q3, q4, q5)) AS PT
```